# DevExpress XtraTabControl HeaderOrientation is not working

Tags: c#, devexpress, tabcontrol

Dears,

I have WinForms application and I need to change XtraTabControl1's HeaderOrientation to Horizontal. Even it works design time, but runtime it isis displayed as Vertical. However, in the same application in different Form it works as expected. Could you pls help on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Off hand, I would think something in the code has to be changing it back to vertical -- perhaps in the form load or form shown event?  If you've searched the entire code for `HeaderOrientation` and don't see anything, can you attach a screen shot of the designer?

Comment: Also, have you tried hard-coding it to horizontal in the form load event?

Comment: Thanks. Pls, look a this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xZ-UMDIjGPs&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Wow, so far all I can do is credit you for a decent question...  One follow-up.  If you add a brand-new tab control to your XtraForm3 (along side the existing one), does it still demonstrate this behavior?

Comment: Yes, it does not work. Pls look: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DEf0ea05Hh4&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: If you use below options of XtraTabControl, then problem is raising:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.xtraTabControl1.LookAndFeel.Style = DevExpress.LookAndFeel.LookAndFeelStyle.Flat;
            this.xtraTabControl1.LookAndFeel.UseDefaultLookAndFeel = false;
        }
```

Thanks.